# ACF - get custom taxonomy term image field

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I have loop that displays all terms from custom taxonomy. I also have image field, attached to custom taxonomy. Now, I want to display image in my page template:

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Služby */
  
get_header();
?>

<section id="sluzby" class="section--padding" style="background: #eff1f5;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <?php       
            $terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'sluzba', 'hide_empty' => false ) );
            $term_image = get_field( 'tax_image' );
                    
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) : ?>
            
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                    <div class="product product-zoom product--card">
                        <div class="product__thumbnail">

                            <?php //if ( $term_image ) : ?>

                                <img src="<?php echo $term_image['url']; ?>" alt="Služba <?php echo $term->name; ?>">

                            <?php //endif; ?>

                        </div>

                        <div class="product-desc">
                            <h4 class="text-center mb-2"><?php echo $term->name; ?></h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>              
            
            <?php
            endforeach
            ?>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<?php
get_footer();
```

[image]

Comment: try to put `$term_image = get_field( 'tax_image' );` inside your foreach loop (because you need to get image for every term) and pass term object inside get_field function, like this - `$term_image = get_field( 'tax_image', $term );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by this example:

https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/loop-to-display-acf-image-of-taxonomy-term/

```
<?php       
$terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'sluzba', 'hide_empty' => false ) );

foreach ( $terms as $term ) : 
    $term_image = get_field( 'tax_image', 'sluzba_' . $term->term_id ); ?>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
        <div class="product product-zoom product--card">
            <div class="product__thumbnail">

                <?php if ( $term_image ) : ?>

                    <img src="<?php echo $term_image['url']; ?>" alt="Služba <?php echo $term->name; ?>">

                <?php endif; ?>

            </div>

            <div class="product-desc">
                <h4 class="text-center mb-2"><?php echo $term->name; ?></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>              

<?php
endforeach
?>
```